# How to generate random number in specific range with X number of duplicates in google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I can't figure out how to solve my issue in google spreadsheet.

I have a column with some packages we want to release on our website on specific random dates. Not all fields in these column are populated, some are empty. For the populated ones I want to assign a random number between a range (A,B) which I take from other fields and have a max number of duplicates (the number of duplicates I take from another field).

For example I have 60 packages and I need to assign them between 1 and 31 (days of current month) so that means I will have 2 duplicates/day and I will put my duplicate field value to 2. But these 60 packages are shown in 80 rows for example, 20 rows empty, so those must not have any number assigned to them.

I have tried a few solutions with RANDBETWEEN and SORT etc but I did not manage to make it work. Now I switched to writing a custom function but I have never written one in google app scripts before, so if any of you guys have experience with this I would highly appreciate.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

### Random dates

**Use this formula** to get random dates between start date and end date appended randomly and duplicated only twice.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,
              VLOOKUP(A2:A,
                      {SORT({ FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>""),
                              RANDARRAY(COUNTA( FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")),1) },2,1),
                       TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(TEXTJOIN(";",1,($E$1+SEQUENCE(DATEDIF($E$1,$E$2,"D"),1,1)))&";",$E$5),";"))},3,0)))
```

[image]

### Sort chronologically

**01 -** paste in `G2`.

```
=SORT(QUERY(UNIQUE(QUERY({B2:B},"Select * where Col1 is not null ")), "where Col1 is not null"),1,1)
```

[image]

**02 -** paste this formula in `H2` and drag down.

```
=IF(G2="",,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER($A$2:$A,$B$2:$B=G2)))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your fast answer. You actually understood my requirements very well. It kind of works but for example if I increase the number of packages it will require more duplicates than 2 in the same timeframe. If i put more duplicates, the function expects more entries. also i might have a smaller timeframe between the dates, so might only be 15 days for example. I will try to adjust the function, but really appreciate your help